# Can a name used in define be redefined in php?

Tags: php, constants

Can a define be redefined in PHP?

e.g.

```
define("__root__", "/some/path");
```

Can the name `__root__` be redefined?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's a fair question.

Comment: The topic of the question might be fair, but I find that the question is very short and adds no context. It's just asking if possible which can be tested faster than asked. (I did not downvote).

Comment: @WillVousden I agree! its a fair question. whoever downvoted, Why the downvote?

Comment: @hakre I did try to search. as usual in my absent mindedness forgot to use proper keywords. Moronic me!

Comment: Eventually because of [that](http://bit.ly/ylkAHh). Look, already the second result is the solution to your problem.

Comment: @leo problem was not that I did not look at the second result. the problem was I did a search for this: [`php redefine a define`](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+redefine+a+define&pbx=1&oq=php+redefine+a+define&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=0l0l1l85273l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&biw=1280&bih=778&ech=1&psi=ThIIT8e9GMPjrAet9MHMDw.1325929039033.5&emsg=NCSR&noj=1&ei=qRIIT7SlKJDIrQfiwezxDw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-constant-redefine.php

It's there, just don't do it.

Comment: Damn! should have used proper keywords when I searched. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey: don't forget it is PECL extension and no one installs it

Comment: Although, `runkit` an extension  and needs to be installed separately. So, `PHP does not support redefining implicitly`.
edit: @zerkms hadn't seen your comment.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey: Not by default, right. You can extend or hack it however.

Answer (score 1):

Constant is called constant because it is constant.

Answer (score 1):

No, the idea of constants in PHP is that they can't be redefined. If you wan't to do this eventually you could use just variables or the `$_GLOBALS` array.